# State parameters outside of the url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to pass parameters to a state without them being represented in the url?

Let's say I have the following state:

```
.state('accounts.content.viewaccounts.details.contacts.edit', {
        url:'/edit/{contactId:[0-9]{1,10}}',
        templateUrl: 'app/common/templates/StandardForm.html',
        resolve: {blahblah}
```

Is there a way for me to send an optional parameter to this state, when navigating to it with $state.go, without adding it into the url?

Comment: why not using shared service and save the data between the states?

Comment: Because I want it to actually act like a paramter. I could, of course, do it with a service but it will add a lot of complexity compared to just passing a parameter.

Comment: not it won't please see my example, not sure if you can do it with a parameter, you always can add a parameter which can be null-able but it should be done with a service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared properties service and pass elements between controllers:

```
.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var item = null;
    return {
        getItem: function () {
            return item;
        },
        setItem: function(value) {
            item = value;
        }
    }});
```

Then before you move to controller you use:

```
sharedProperties.setItem(your-item);
```

and after you load the new controller you use:

```
var model = sharedProperties.getItem();
```

Comment: While this works to pass data between states, It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: ok, it's different solution and also can solve the problem, if i didn't help, don't mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 0):

No. Not without using something like a service. see @Liad's answer